# Cant convert xml file to csv; instead i get an error

Tags: python

I am having trouble converting a bunch of XML files to csv for an object detection project. I was following this link
https://github.com/wagonhelm/TF_ObjectDetection_API/blob/master/ChessObjectDetection.ipynb

```py
imagepath = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\snehal\Desktop\JPEGImages')
labelpath = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\snehal\Desktop\XMLAnnotations')


def xml_to_csv(path):
    xml_list=[]
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for member in root.findall('object'):
            value = (root.find('filename').text,
                     int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                     int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                     member[0].text,
                     int(member[4][0].text),
                     int(member[4][1].text),
                     int(member[4][2].text),
                     int(member[4][3].text)
                     )
            xml_list.append(value)
        column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height', 'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
        xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list,columns=column_name)
        return xml_df



def main():

    for i in imagepath:
        path = i
        folder = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(i))
        xml_df = xml_to_csv(path)
        xml_df.to_csv(path_or_buf=folder +'.csv.',index=None)
        print('Converted')

main()
```

The expected output was supposed to be a lot of csv files in a folder but instead I get an error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/snehal/Desktop/Ansh stuff/Object detection/TEST2.py', wdir='C:/Users/snehal/Desktop/Ansh stuff/Object detection')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-40-caaa983ccae1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/snehal/Desktop/Ansh stuff/Object detection/TEST2.py', wdir='C:/Users/snehal/Desktop/Ansh stuff/Object detection')

  File "C:\Users\snehal\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 826, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\snehal\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/snehal/Desktop/Ansh stuff/Object detection/TEST2.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:/Users/snehal/Desktop/Ansh stuff/Object detection/TEST2.py", line 45, in main
    xml_df.to_csv(path_or_buf=folder +'.csv.',index=None)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may be to do with the line `folder = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(i))`. The value of `i` may not be an actual file path, or you may not have permission to write to it.

You can print out the value of `i` to clarify.

So when the code execution gets to `xml_df.to_csv(path_or_buf=folder +'.csv.',index=None)` the value of `folder` is `None` and so execution cannot continue.

Comment: OMG u were right. the value of i was one. how do i fix this

Comment: I would move the lines defining imagepath and labelpath just above your for loop in the main function. If you still get an error, add a `\`  at the end of both definitions. So for example, imagepath would end with `JPEGImages\`

Comment: I can't edit my comment above from my phone...I'm not sure it rendered correctly.what I meant was add a backslash at the end of the paths if you still get an error

Comment: I just get an error saying: EOL while scanning string leteral